# select statement for averages based on different date ranges in one MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli, aggregate-functions

Basically I am attempting to make a chart with this data. I am able to put my query into a while loop in PHP to get each average, but I would prefer this was done with one query producing one result table.

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

include('../connect.php');

$subcategory = 'T-Shirts';

$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-29 days'));
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$subcategory = mysqli_real_escape_string($conp, $subcategory);

echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>date</th>";
echo "<th>average</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($today)) {

    $from_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("-29 day", strtotime($date)));

    $query = $conp->query("SELECT ROUND(SUM(OutCount)/30) AS 'average' FROM inventory
    LEFT JOIN item
    ON inventory.itemcode = item.itemcode
    WHERE item.subcategory = '$subcategory'
    AND TrDateTime BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$date' AND transactiontype like 'OUT_%'"); 

    if($query->num_rows){       
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){                      
            if(!empty($row['average'])){
                $average = $row['average'];
            }else{
                $average = "N/A";
            }
        }                       
        mysqli_free_result($query);                             
    }else{
        $average = "N/A";
    }

    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $date . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $average . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

I get all the dates in the past 30 days (including today) and the average sales from a range of 29 days prior until that date.

```
+------------+----------+  
| date       | average  |  
+------------+----------+  
| 2015-04-09 | 222      |  
| 2015-04-10 | 225      |  
| 2015-04-11 | 219      |  
| ...        | ...      |  
+------------+----------+
```

I am able to get everything I need this way, but it is running 29 queries in this situation and MySQL would be substantially quicker. I started to come up with a MySQL procedure, but I am not sure how well this will work when I try and call it with PHP.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE average_daily_sales()
    BEGIN

        SET @today = CURDATE();
        SET @date_var = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 29 DAY;
        SET @from_date = @date_var - INTERVAL 29 DAY;
        SET @to_date = @from_date + INTERVAL 29 DAY;

        label1: WHILE @date_var < @today DO

            SELECT      DATE_FORMAT(trdatetime, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'date', ROUND(SUM(OutCount)/30) AS 'average'
            FROM        inventory
            LEFT JOIN   item
            ON          inventory.itemcode = item.itemcode
            WHERE       item.subcategory = 'T-Shirts'
            AND         trdatetime BETWEEN @from_date - INTERVAL 29 DAY AND @to_date
            AND         transactiontype like 'OUT_%';

            SET @date_var = @date_var + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

        END WHILE label1;    

    END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Ultimately, I would prefer a regular MySQL statement that I can use to produce the desired result table in one shot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked into GROUP BY ?

Comment: The averages I am trying to get in my results are based on variable date ranges, I am not sure how I can use GROUP BY in this situation.

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN item... WHERE item` = `INNER JOIN item... WHERE item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestions from @OllieJones and @spencer7593 either required a 'transaction' to take place every day in order to utilize `SELECT DISTINCT DATE(trdatetime)`, you needed to create another table, or you needed to generate a derived table.

`SELECT DISTINCT DATE(trdatetime)` wasn't an option for me because I did not have transactions for everyday.

The hybrid PHP and MySQL example that @spencer7593 suggested would generate a derived table very well. In the end it took the static version about 1.8 seconds to get a result. The issue being that you would need additional PHP to generate this... (see @spencer7593 answer)

```
SELECT cal.dt
     , ( -- correlated subquery references value returned from cal
         SELECT ROUND(SUM(n.OutCount)/30)
           FROM inventory n
           JOIN item t
             ON t.itemcode = n.itemcode
          WHERE t.subcategory = 'foo'
            AND n.TrDateTime >= cal.dt + INTERVAL -28 DAY
            AND n.TrDateTime <  cal.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            AND n.transactiontype LIKE 'OUT_%'
       ) AS `average`
  FROM ( SELECT DATE('2015-04-01') AS dt
        UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-02')
        UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-03')
        UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-04')
        UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-05')
        UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-06')
etc...
       ) cal
 WHERE cal.dt >= '2015-04-01'
   AND cal.dt <  '2015-05-01'
 ORDER BY cal.dt
```

I am attempted to use another one of @spencer7593 answers. I created a "source of integers" table with the numbers 0-31 as he suggested. This method took a little over 1.8 seconds.

```
SELECT cal.sd, cal.ed
     , ( -- correlated subquery references value returned from cal
         SELECT ROUND(SUM(n.OutCount)/30)
           FROM inventory n
           JOIN item t
             ON t.itemcode = n.itemcode
          WHERE t.subcategory = 'foobar'
            AND n.TrDateTime >= cal.ed + INTERVAL -30 DAY
            AND n.TrDateTime <  cal.ed + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            AND n.transactiontype LIKE 'OUT_%'
       ) AS `average`
  FROM ( SELECT (CURDATE() + INTERVAL -30 DAY) + INTERVAL i.n DAY as `ed`, (((CURDATE() + INTERVAL -30 DAY) + INTERVAL i.n DAY) + INTERVAL - 30 DAY) as `sd`
            FROM source_of_integers i
           WHERE i.n >= 0
             AND i.n < 31
           ORDER BY i.n
        ) cal
WHERE cal.ed >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL -29 DAY
   AND cal.ed <=  CURDATE()
 ORDER BY cal.ed;
```

You need a rowsource for these dates, there isn't really a way around that. In the end I made a cal table..

```
CREATE TABLE cal (
    dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE ints ( i tinyint );

INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

INSERT INTO cal (dt)
SELECT DATE('2010-01-01') + INTERVAL a.i*10000 + b.i*1000 + c.i*100 + d.i*10 + e.i DAY
FROM ints a JOIN ints b JOIN ints c JOIN ints d JOIN ints e
WHERE (a.i*10000 + b.i*1000 + c.i*100 + d.i*10 + e.i) <= 3651
ORDER BY 1;
```

And then ran a slightly modified version of @spencer7593 answer on it..

```
SELECT cal.dt
     , ( -- correlated subquery references value returned from cal
         SELECT ROUND(SUM(n.OutCount)/30)
           FROM inventory n
           JOIN item t
             ON t.itemcode = n.itemcode
          WHERE t.subcategory = 'foo'
            AND n.TrDateTime >= cal.dt + INTERVAL -28 DAY
            AND n.TrDateTime <  cal.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            AND n.transactiontype LIKE 'OUT_%'
       ) AS `average`
  FROM cal
WHERE cal.dt >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL -30 DAY
    AND cal.dt <  CURDATE()
ORDER BY cal.dt;
```

In my opinion, I believe this is the cleanest (less PHP) and highest performing answer.

Here is how I indexed the inventory table to speed it up substantially:

`ALTER TABLE inventory ADD KEY (ItemCode, TrDateTime, TransactionType);`

Thank you @OllieJones and @spencer7593 for all of your help!

Comment: Nicely done. You've done an investigation, and considered several possible alternatives. The aggregation itself is rather straightforward. If we describe this problem space using data warehouse terminology, what you've got is a "fact table" that is "sparse", and you need a "dimension table" for the date values. The dimension table can be used to "fill in the gaps", and generate results (even zero counts) for all values in the dimension table, even when those values are missing from the "fact table".

Answer (score 2):

If you create a calender table and populate that with a range of date values, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE cal (dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ;
INSERT INTO cal VALUES ('2015-04-01'),('2015-04-02'),('2015-04-03'), ... ;
```

you could use that as a row source, in a query like this:

```
SELECT cal.dt
     , ( -- correlated subquery references value returned from cal
         SELECT ROUND(SUM(n.OutCount)/30)
           FROM inventory n
           JOIN item t
             ON t.itemcode = n.itemcode
          WHERE t.subcategory = 'foo'
            AND n.TrDateTime >= cal.dt + INTERVAL -28 DAY
            AND n.TrDateTime <  cal.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            AND n.transactiontype LIKE 'OUT_%'
       ) AS `average`
  FROM cal
 WHERE cal.dt >= '2015-04-01'
   AND cal.dt <  '2015-05-01'
 ORDER BY cal.dt
```

It's not mandatory to create a `cal` calendar table. We could use an inline view and give it an alias of `cal`. For example, in the query above, we could replace this line:

```
  FROM cal
```

with this:

```
  FROM ( SELECT DATE('2015-04-01') AS dt
         UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-02')
         UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-03')
         UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-04')
         UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-05')
       ) cal
```

Or, if you have a rowsource that can give you a contiguous series of integers, starting at zero up t you could manufacture your date values from a base date, for example

```
   FROM ( SELECT '2014-04-01' + INTERVAL i.n DAY
            FROM source_of_integers i
           WHERE i.n >= 0
             AND i.n < 31
           ORDER BY i.n
        ) cal
```

Some notes:

The original query shows an outer (`LEFT`) join, but the equality predicate in the WHERE clause negates the "outerness" of the join, it's equivalent to an inner join.

Some of the column references in the query are not qualified. Best practice is to qualify all column references, then the reader can understand which columns are coming from which tables, without requiring the reader to be familiar with which columns are in which tables. This also protects the statement from breaking in the future (with an "ambiguous column" error) when a column that has the same name is added to another table referenced in the query.)

**FOLLOWUP**

Personally, for a limited number of date values, I'd go with the inline view that doesn't reference a table. I'd have the PHP code generate that query for me.

With a starting date, say it's '2015-04-10', I'd take that date value and format it into a query, equivalent doing this:

```
$cal = "SELECT DATE('2015-04-10') AS dt" ;
```

Then I'd spin through a loop, and increment that date value by 1 day. Each time through the loop, I'd appending to `$cal` a select of the next date, the net effect of running through the loop three times would be equivalent to doing this:

```
$cal .= " UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-11')";
$cal .= " UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-12')";
$cal .= " UNION ALL SELECT DATE('2015-04-13')";
```

As a less attractive alternative, we could keep repeating the same value of the start date, and just increment an integer value, and let MySQL do the date math for us.

```
$cal .= " UNION ALL SELECT '2015-04-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY";
$cal .= " UNION ALL SELECT '2015-04-10' + INTERVAL 2 DAY";
$cal .= " UNION ALL SELECT '2015-04-10' + INTERVAL 3 DAY";
```

Then, I'd just slide the `$cal` query into the SQL text as an inline view query. Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT cal.dt
             , ( SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(SUM
                 ,0) AS average_
          FROM ( " . $cal . " ) cal
          LEFT
          JOIN item ON ... ";
```

Anyway, that's the approach I'd take if this was for a *limited* number of date values (a couple dozen or so), and if I was only going to be running this query occasionally, not hammering the database server with this query repeatedly, for every request.)  If I was going to pound the server, I'd create and maintain a real `cal` table, rather than incur the overhead of materializing a derived table on every query.

Comment: MariaDB has a SEQUENCE access method.  `SELECT seq FROM seq_0_TO_30` yields that nice stream of integers.

Comment: @OllieJones: Yes. That's not available in MySQL (yet!). In Oracle, we can use a odd looking `SELECT level FROM DUAL CONNECT BY` subquery as a rowsource to get a contiguous sequence of integers.

Comment: @OllieJones My only issue with this solution is that I need a sequence table which could potentially add 4 seconds to my query time if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @JustinEmmons: What this query needs (just like Ollie's query) is a **rowsource** for date values. Or, a rowsource that can be used to derive the date values. Contiguous integer values are very handy for that. For optimum performance, a short, properly indexed table is the ideal choice. (Like the example table `cal` at the beginning of my answer.) The big downside (as you noted in an earlier comment) is that the query is now dependent on having an additional "extra" table populated. Personally, I like the inline view that doesn't reference a table, the first replacement of `cal` that I show.

Comment: @spencer7593 I read through your FOLLOW UP answer and this hybrid solution using PHP to generate the derived table was basically the idea I had in my head. I did notice the strain on the DB when I ran the static version of this query. Now I'm starting to think just having a 'source_of_integers' table with 0-31 in it and using that to generate the date sequence is the best solution.

Comment: @JustinEmmons: In terms best performance, again, I believe having a *small* table that is appropriate *indexed* is going to give the best performance. The `cal` table I gave an example of, at the beginning of my answer, is an actual table that we have in production. We've got that table populated with dates values to the end of 2019. (Seems to me that this should be an automatic feature of the DBMS, a builtin table valued function that would return a set of integers, or dates, in a specified range.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have data on each distinct day in the range?  If so, this is a slightly complex join operation, but very doable.

You can get the date ranges you need as follows:

```
        SELECT DISTINCT
               DATE(trdatetime)- INTERVAL 30 DAY AS startdate,
               DATE(trdatetime)                  AS enddateplus1
          FROM inventory
         WHERE trdatetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY
```

Debug this query. Take a look to make sure you get each date range you want.

Then you can join this to your business query like so

```
  SELECT dates.startdate, 
         ROUND(SUM(OutCount)/30) AS 'average'
   FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               DATE(trdatetime)- INTERVAL 30 DAY AS startdate,
               DATE(trdatetime)                  AS enddateplus1
          FROM inventory
         WHERE trdatetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY
        ) dates
   LEFT JOIN inventory  ON i.trdatetime >= dates.startdate
                       AND i.trdatetime <  dates.enddateplus1 
   LEFT JOIN  item ON  i.itemcode = item.itemcode
  WHERE item.subcategory = 'T-Shirts'
    AND transactiontype like 'OUT_%'
  GROUP BY dates.startdate
```

If your inventory data is sparse, that is, you don't have transactions on all days, then your dates query will be missing some rows.

There's a way to fill in those missing rows. But it's a pain in the *s*. Read this for more info.  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Notice that `BETWEEN` works very badly indeed for filtering `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` values.

Comment: I concur with the observation about using `BETWEEN` with `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME`. I find it much more convenient, less error prone, and more satisfying to use a pattern such as `t.trdatetime >= '2014-04-10' AND t.trdatetime < '2014-04-10' + INTERVAL 30 DAY`.  We use a "greater than or equal to" the start, and a "less than" the very first point in time that is outside our range. (I've seen way too many examples that inadvertently leave out the whole day at the end. And there shouldn't be an overlap that includes midnight of the following day. (A datetime should fall in one bucket, not two.)

Comment: @JustinEmmons: To get this approach, or the approach in my answer to work, you need a rowsource for dates. In the Ollie's example statment, the inline view aliased as `dates` is actually called (in the MySQL venacular) a *derived table*. It's very convenient to use an inline view as a row source, without having to run a separate `create temporaray table foo (dt) as` in a separate step. The query in this answer uses a JOIN operation. The query in my answer uses correlated subquery in the select list. Both queries use some sort of row source to get date values from.

Comment: Ollie: the equality predicates in the `WHERE` clause *negate* the "outerness" of the outer joins. If we want these to be outer joins, those predicates can be relocated to the appropriate `ON` clause. Otherwise, the `LEFT` keyword isn't having any affect on the resultset.

Comment: @spencer7593 I am determined to dynamically generate this statement without any alternative rowsource. I am thinking it might be possible by creating the inline view with some PHP and inserting it into the query using a variable. My end goal is to increase the performance of my software, and using 1 query seems to be the ticket in this case.

Comment: @spencer7593, you're quite right about the negation of the left joins.

Comment: Note that this line: `LEFT JOIN  item ON  i.itemcode = item.itemcode
  WHERE item.subcategory = 'T-Shirts'` renders as an inner join